# Redirecting to angular sub module

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service, angular-routing

I have a angular client application hosted as a web service app in azure. Assume, it has got two modules - "ModuleA" and "ModuleB".

In Godaddy, I have two CNAME records pointing to the azure website. For example, if my root domain name is contoso.com , I have two CNAME records "moduleA.contoso.com"  and "moduleb.contoso.com" in godaddy DNS records.

What I would like to achieve is redirect the user to the default component of the modules based on the URL that the user has typed in the browser. Meaning, if they type modulea.contoso.com, I want the user to be taken to the default component of the ModuleA present in my angular client application.

Please advise how you would achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to route based on a subdomain with Angular or any other JavaScript router for that matter.

So here are 2 workarounds for you:

1. Use URL path instead of a subdomain, like the URL path `moduleA.contoso.com/moduleA`
2. Route from the server-side, for example, using [IIS rewrite rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to rewrite `moduleA.contoso.com` to `moduleA.contoso.com/moduleA`